# WebView is "unable to get property 'length'..."?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I got big problem with WebView for VS 2013, C#, Metro. I try to navigate to site: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/liveevents/windows-8-1-developer-training-geek-edition and it throws the error message: **unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null referebce**. I downloaded the Metro examples pack for c# and tried the program XAML WebView control sample too. Pasted above URL and the same problem happened. I have no idea if WebView is bugged or I just miss a property, but other sites work just fine. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?